# How to ask user nicely to upload their profile picture

Tags: sentence-construction

I am a web developer by profession and does not have good English writing/speaking skills.

I want to ask my website visitors to upload their profile picture after they have created an account on my website, so that their profile looks better to other website visitors

but I am unable to make a nice sentence that attracts the application user to upload their profile picture

Comment: Can you give an example of another web-site that does something similar?

Comment: Could you provide your own attempt and tells us why you think it is wrong or unsatisfactory? Otherwise, this seems like a broad request.

Answer (score 1):

Please upload a picture to make your profile stand out!